# Unit Testing Controllers in PHP - Should I mock everything?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, zend-framework2

Basically, i have an application written in Zend Framework 2.
My Controllers are pretty good tested, and while i made this experience i asked my self:

"Should i mock everything i can possibly mock?"

For example:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $form = new SomeForm();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Now: Should i mock the form? I learned its the best to mock as much as possible.
On the other hand, i've read that there is something called "overmocking" which basically means, that if you mock too much, its bad because the test might be broken.

Comment: I wouldn't unit test controllers. Unit test your models and classes which have business logic like services. You can use BDD (Behat) to test flow of your application end to end. This way you are not mocking anything and are testing the controllers properly. You can use different drivers for testing: headless like Goutte (good for pages without JS) or JavaScript enabled drivers for JS heavy pages, for example Selenium 2 or Zombie driver.

Comment: BDD doesn't limit you to testing one controller action at a time but rather allows you to test entire flow of a specific functionality on your website, which probably includes several controller actions and interactions between them. For example, you could write a BDD scenario to test registration flow. This BDD would first open the page with registration form, fill in the fields, submit the form, check that you have received the activation email (to check emails I am logging all sent emails on my CI server so I just check the email log), go to the activation link, then go to the login page...

Answer (score 0):

I think you've asked two separate questions here, so I'll try to answer them both.

**Should I mock everything?**

In general, you should mock *as little as possible* to test the functionality. If you mock as much as possible, you don't ever truly see how your methods interact with each other (not *integrate*, as integration testing is a distinct concept).

**How should I test this controller action?**

In your example, and in line with my first answer, I would only "mock" the request object, and even in this case, I wouldn't actually make a mock (in the using `getMock(..)` sense of things), I would just construct a `Request` object manually. Apologies if this is not syntactically correct, I am writing this off my head:

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
$request->setPost(new Parameters([/* array with whatever parameters your form might need */]));
$request->setMethod('POST');

$controller = new YourController();
$controller->setRequest($request); // you may need to use a \ReflectionProperty to do this
$controller->someAction();
```

I would create the POST parameters using data providers to test a variety of different inputs to check that what you expect to happen *will happen*.

If some undesired effect would happen by calling `doSomething()`, then it may help if you mocked that method. Because `doSomething()` appears to be just a function rather than a class method, you may need some different code. However, for simplicity, lets tweak your initial example to be a call to `$this->doSomething()`, our test would change to something like this:

```
// set up $request as before

$controller = $this->getMock('\Your\Vendor\Controller\YourController', ['doSomething']);
$controller->expects($this->once())->method('doSomething');
$controller->setRequest($request); // you may need to use a \ReflectionProperty to do this
$controller->someAction();
```

This asserts that the "doSomething" method is called (if you want to verify that it's called).